# How to prepare input for classification learner app?

Tags: matlab, svm, multiclass-classification

My work is on speech recognition. And this is what I have so far:

**FOR TRAINING**

> I have `input vector matrix (training data)` of size `11811x65 double`, corresponding response of size `1*65 double`.

**FOR TESTING**

> I have a matrix of size `5942x11 double`.

I want to use classification learner app having "Multiclass SVM".

**How should I give input to classification learner app?**

1. Do we only give training data and its corresponding output?
2. Can give both training as well as testing data simultaneously to the app?
3. ? (Maybe I'm doing it all wrong?)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you have 65 observations in your training data X and 11 in the testing data Z ? right?

1. create table:

   ```
   train = array2table(X);
   train.Group = Y;% labels
   ```
2. train SVM using the classification learner
3. export the trained model let suppost that is named trainedsvm
4. now you can classify your testing data

   ```
   test = array2table(Z(:,1:11811));
   test.Group = U;% labels
   [predictedlabel,scores] = predict(trainedsvm,test);
   ```